# Why shouldn't rails noobs use Gem Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

I am a ruby on rails noob. In contrast I am fairly good in my HTML CSS javascript and jQuery. Recently I got into ruby on rails using this tutorial by Michael Hartl: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book  .

But alas I am trying to build my own project and use [gem devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) as a simple way to do authentication. As it is difficult for a beginner to do authentication. However, everyone is mentioning that noobs should not use this gem.

Why shouldn't a noob use devise for his own project?

Thanks for any tips at all but I would much prefer a verbose answer.

Comment: Do you always listen to people who tell you you can't do things? Try it. If you manage it, good, if you don't, ask for help. Your current question, however, is off-topic.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld I don't think it's off topic. If anything it's badly phrased, but it's a legitimate question in my opinion.

Comment: @Mohamad: it is indeed badly phrased. "is devise easy to use/how do I use devise?" would have been a lot less subjective/biased than "why shouldn't a noob use devise?". the first asks for advice, the second for opinions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I completely disagree with the advice you've been given so far, including from the other answers here.

Rolling your own authentication, especially as a beginner, is a good way to put your users at risk. Security (and especially crypto) is hard and you'll probably get it wrong somehow even if you have experience.

If you want to learn how password-based authentication works (and you should), learn it on your free time. Don't make your users unwitting test subjects and put their privacy at risk.

Comment: I agree in principle. But there are many other things that could put your users at risk. Building applications without having any real knowledge of how the framework or the language work could pose the same risks. I would argue that you should not be building a serious app before you know the fundamentals of security. Using Devise will not teach you this.

Comment: ... nor will it teach you about scoping resources to current users, and so on.

Comment: So your argument is that because you can make mistakes elsewhere, you shouldn't care if you make mistakes with auth?

Comment: If you don't make mistakes you'll never learn. Using a gem may help you avoid mistakes, but it neither makes your app safer nor you a better programmer. "Writing your own auth is risky" is nonsense. It doesn't take a genius to write auth. Auth is built on abstraction libraries; you're not reinventing the wheel or writing cryptography. You're utilising an API. So before starting a serious app, what do you do? You learn the API. Using Devise will leave you likely to make your mistakes else where. With or without Devise, you'd still be an ignorant programmer until you learn the API.

Comment: Huh.  Seems like the developers of Devise disagree with you: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#starting-with-rails

Answer (score 5):

Unless you plan to use Devise out of the box without any modifications, using Devise could cost you more time than writing your own authentication.

It depends on how complex your your needs are. For example, whether you need a forgotten password feature, a verification feature, etc...

Implementing your own authentication is extremely simple with Rails' `has_secure_password`. It is also very helpful to know what is going on behind the scenes. It's part of the learning process, it's trivial, and fun.

It literally takes about 10 lines of code to write a basic auth. As others have said, unless you have a pressing need, just follow the tutorial. You will learn a lot of good things from it, and using Devise will cause you to miss a lot of great information.

Comment: I disagree with some of this answer. Devise has like 10 different modules built in (rememberable, forgot_password, etc) and it would take you much more than 10 lines to create these modules as part of rolling your own Auth.

Comment: @Catfish, point taken. Although a `remember_me` feature takes about 6 lines. I'll clarify.

Comment: Learning how to create users from scratch, without using generators for anything but migrations was the first time I felt like I really understood how rails works, it teaches you routes, what order controllers are called in, what before_filter/before_action is, how to access information from a model that isn't the same as the controller. I tried using Devise before rolling my own, and I found Devise was a headache compared to rolling my own. OO is your most powerful gem, learn it.

Answer (score 4):

The idea is that, as a noob, learning the basics of how authentication works is really useful.  Even if in future projects you end up using Devise all the time, having the experience of developing your own authentication so you know what's going on behind the scenes in Devise is really helpful.

You need to make your own decision on this.  If you're in a hurry to get an app out the door, learning how to use Devise first might be the right way to go.  If you have the time though, trying to figure out how to roll your own is a good idea.  At the very least, it's worth your time to check out Ryan Bates video on rolling your own: http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

Also, this from the Devise documentation discouraging new rails devs from using Devise:  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#starting-with-rails